# Job for kube-apiserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: kubernetes, centos7

On the beginning i wanted to point out i am fairly new into Linux systems, and totally, totally new with kubernetes so my question may be trivial.

As stated in the title i have problem with setting up the Kubernetes cluster. I am working on the Atomic Host `Version: 7.1707 (2017-07-31 16:12:06)`

I am following this guide: 
http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/gettingstarted/
in addition to that i followed this:
http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/kubernetes/
(to be precise, i ran this command: 
`rpm-ostree install kubernetes-master --reboot`

everything was going fine until this point:

```
systemctl start etcd kube-apiserver kube-controller-manager kube-scheduler
```

the problem is with:

```
systemctl start etcd kube-apiserver
```

as it gives me back this response:

> Job for kube-apiserver.service failed because the control process
>   exited with error code. See "systemctl status kube-apiserver.service"
>   and "journalctl -xe" for details.

```
systemctl status kube-apiserver.service
```

gives me back:

```
● kube-apiserver.service - Kubernetes API Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kube-apiserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Fri 2017-08-25 14:29:56 CEST; 2s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
  Process: 17876 ExecStart=/usr/bin/kube-apiserver $KUBE_LOGTOSTDERR $KUBE_LOG_LEVEL $KUBE_ETCD_SERVERS $KUBE_API_ADDRESS $KUBE_API_PORT $KUBELET_PORT $KUBE_ALLOW_PRIV $KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES $KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL $KUBE_API_ARGS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 17876 (code=exited, status=255)

Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: Failed to start Kubernetes API Server.
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: Unit kube-apiserver.service entered failed state.
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service failed.
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for kube-apiserver.service
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: Failed to start Kubernetes API Server.
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: Unit kube-apiserver.service entered failed state.
Aug 25 14:29:56 master systemd[1]: kube-apiserver.service failed.
```

I have no clue where to start and i will be more than thankful for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a typo in /etc/kubernetes/config. I misunderstood the "# Comma separated list of nodes in the etcd cluster".

Idk how to close the thread or anything.